# Plotting GTFS object routes with tidytransit in R

Tags: r, gtfs

I need to plot General transit Feed Specification (GTFS) object routes and their frequencies. For this purpose I have run the following code from the package manual https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytransit/tidytransit.pdf
to get some practice. But although the code is taken from the manual, I do get the error below. Is there anyone who can clarify this issue and show me an alternative way to perform spatial analysis?

```
library(tidytransit)
local_gtfs_path <- system.file("extdata",
                   "google_transit_nyc_subway.zip",
                   package = "tidytransit")

nyc <- read_gtfs(local_gtfs_path,
                   local=TRUE)

plot(nyc)
```

Error in UseMethod("inner_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for posting this!

this happened because we made a change in the API and I think the docs you were looking at were out of sync. they should be up to date now. see http://tidytransit.r-transit.org/articles/introduction.html

also, we made a change so that the plot() function will work as specified in the old docs and in the new docs.